# Windows indexed files OLE DB search with like instead of contains

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, oledb, windows-search

So I have the problem that I need to exchange this contains, with a like in my query. Because when you search with a dash in a word so "12-0430-1" then the contains produces results that also contain only 12 or 0430 or 1. This is intended and also spoken about by microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/dashes-ignored-search-full-text-msidxs-queries). Also the solution is in this article, but sadly only in a way that does not help. The solution is to exchange contains with like, but I always get an error with this edited query:

```
SELECT TOP 2000 System.FileName 
FROM systemindex  
WHERE DIRECTORY = 'C:\Path...' 
  AND (System.FullText Like ('%12-0430-1%'))  
ORDER BY System.DateCreated DESC
```

The error says because the column does not exist, but for OLE DB search I only found this older site which specifies which columns can be [searched](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ff521735(v=vs.85)).

Before I did not need it because I used contains:

> Ole-DB query: for 22-0130-1  SELECT TOP 2000 System.FileName FROM
> systemindex   WHERE DIRECTORY = 'C:\Path'   AND (CONTAINS
> ('"12-0430-1*"'))   ORDER BY System.DateCreated DESC

So could somebody please link me a page with the current columns that can be searched over windows indexed files or say which column exists and would be working, I want to search through the indexed contents of the file.

Edit these are my settings with which I create the `OleDBConnection`:

```
OleDbConnection connection =
     new OleDbConnection("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';");
```

Comment: wouldn't you need to declare the system alias? `FROM systemindex as System` ?

Comment: The other querry works flawless, but I can try.

Comment: @RandRandom I still get the same Error the Querry now looks like this:
 SELECT TOP 2000 System.FileName FROM systemindex as System WHERE DIRECTORY = 'C:\Path' AND (System.FullText Like ('%12-0430-1%'))  ORDER BY System.DateCreated DESC

Comment: Not sure what the error might be, but maybe you can overcome it with a nested select. `select t1.name from (SELECT TOP 2000 System.FileName FROM systemindex WHERE DIRECTORY = 'C:\Path...' ORDER BY System.DateCreated DESC) as t1 where t1.name like '%blub%'` never dealed without those system things

Comment: @RandRandom This did not help, do you have maybe a other idea?

Comment: Sadly no, good luck. Maybe consider adding the tag `sql`. the tags winapi and windows-search seem unrelated to your question, as they cover diffrent areas.

Comment: @RandRandom thanks for the tip I just did, yeah thats smart there more people in those tags, maybe a upvote would also help ^^